# Emacs / AUCTeX Preserve highlights from other modes after apply style hooks

Tags: emacs, auctex

I use additional Emacs modes in conjunction with AUCTeX, such as
`writegood-mode` and `rainbow-delimiters-mode`, which each add their
custom highlights to the current buffer. Unfortunately, after
refreshing AUCTeX style hooks (`C-n`), the highlights are gone
and I have to manually disable and re-enable the other modes.
Is there an effective way to do this automatically each time after
`C-n`? I was not able to find a hook that is executed after the style
hook refresh.

Comment: Have you tried `TeX-update-style-hook` hook?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I must have overlooked this hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook you're looking for is `TeX-update-style-hook`.  Its documentation (<kbd>C-h v</kbd> `TeX-update-style-hook` <kbd>RET</kbd>) reads

> Hook run as soon as style specific hooks were applied.

To be precise, it's run at the end of the function `TeX-update-style`, which is called when (re-)opening a new TeX buffer or when `TeX-normal-mode` is executed.